# Want to check if the prefixes of the phone number is valid or not?

Tags: java, android

so in my program the user has to register and one of the fields to enter is the phone number.

I want to check if the first 3 numbers they enter is valid or not

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PhoneNumber) || PhoneNumber != "055, 050, 056, 052") {
     PhoneNumber.setError("Please enter a valid phone number")
     return;`
}
```

this is my code but it set off so many errors, can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: `PhoneNumber != "055, 050, 056, 052"` what is this??

Answer (score 0):

`PhoneNumber != "055, 050, 056, 052"` is wrong.

You can create a string array and store them there.
 `String okNums = {"055", "050", "056", "052"};`

and then check if the phone number is valid

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PhoneNumber) || 
   !Arrays.asList(okNums ).contains(PhoneNumber)) {

    PhoneNumber.setError("Please enter a valid phone number")
    return;`
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

turn your pattern into an array and search if the phone is beginning with any of those

```
String d = "055, 050, 056, 052";
String p = "055 66";
String[] pArr = d.split(",");    
for (String patt : pArr ) {
    System.out.println(patt.trim());
    System.out.println(p.indexOf(patt)==0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Get the string from the edit text by:
     String number = yourEditText.getText().toString();

     if(number != null && number.matches("639[0-9]{9}"))
     //do what you need to do for valid input
     else
     //do what you need to do for invalid input
```

matches() ensures that the entire string cooresponds (exactly) to the regular expression that it takes. 639[0-9]{9} says that the string must start off with 639 and then be followed by exactly 9 digits (0-9). If you wanted to match "639" followed by 7 to 9 numbers, for example, you would use: 639[0-9]{7,9}. Regular expressions:

Comment: if i wanted to add more than "639" would i put ("639[0-9]{9}") , ("640[0-9]{9}") ??

Comment: not separate it from ",".Instead of this you can use with OR operator.Like this:
 if(number != null && number.matches("639[0-9]{9}") || number.matches("640[0-9]{9}"))

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be `.startsWith()`

```
if (!PhoneNumber.startsWith("055") || !PhoneNumber.startsWith("050") || !PhoneNumber.startsWith("056") || !PhoneNumber.startsWith("052")) {
    // does not match
}
```

Another option is to use a regex for this

```
if (!PhoneNumber.matches("^(055|050|056|052)\d+$")){
    // does not match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The worst thing you had done is, your comparison. You can't compare like this, when you need to compare with several values. Instead you have to use something like `List#contains` method to check whether your `PhoneNumber` or not.

```
    String[] check = {"055", "050", "056", "052" };

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PhoneNumber) || Arrays.asList(check).contains(PhoneNumber.getText().toString())) {   

     PhoneNumber.setError("Please enter a valid phone number")
     return;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so from what I understood here is a solution, if the phone number has is a one full string you can extract the first 3 numbers using this:

```
String s="052487978";
String ex = s.substring(0,3));//052
```

Create a int array and store all the valid options in there
`int[] array = {055, 050, 056, 052};` and covert the string ex to int `int value = Integer.parseInt(ex);` and check if its available in the string that contains valid options.

```
boolean contains = IntStream.of(array ).anyMatch(x -> x == value);
```

If it is true its valid and if its false its invalid.